# "this.setState is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code to save the actual region of the map. I dont know what I am doing wrong, y set the state with the same name .

```
state = {
  region: {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  }
};

onRegionChange(region) {
  this.setState({ region });
}

render() {
  return (
    MapView
      style={{ height: 600 }}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `this.setState` is? I'd bet `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}`